# Command pattern in php applications: how to handle controller actions?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, domain-driven-design

I think this is more of a general question (so not php restricted) with regards to ddd and the command pattern.

Let's say I execute a CreatePostCommand from within the create action of my controller, the command will be handled and eventually executed successfully. What's the appropriate way to notify the controller which response to return in case the command did fail or succeed? Given the command handler will fire a domain specific event, I could hook up the controller to the event, but that seems a quite awkward, also not appropriate for every situation (e.g. a post could be created somewhere else and the controller really doesn't know about this :) ).

```
public function createAction($title, $content)
{
    $this->commandBus->execute(new CreatePostCommand($title, $content);

    $this->render('…'); // what if the command execution failed?
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If the execution failed, then an exception would have been thrown, meaning the line you have commented would not have been ran.

Comment: Yes sure. I should have been more specific here. Let's say the command executed successfully and I want to redirect to /post/edit/{$id}, the controller would not be aware of the post id unless both, the controller and the command handler share e.g. the posts repository. Does this make more sense.

Comment: Returning values from a command will break the pattern. So yes you are correct in that both controller and command handler will need to know about the repo. But if you need to have something returning from a command have a look at the functor pattern.

Comment: Well, I don't expect the command to return anything. I'm looking for an appropriate way to let the controller know which response to return.

Comment: Well returning an appropriate value from your command will help you determine which response to return. Either that or use your repository to check if the data was entered or not, then again return the appropriate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are really trying to follow the DDD command pattern then you need to treat the command bus as a fire and forget asynchronous process that may take a long time to complete.

Consider immediately redirecting to a command verifier controller.  It's up to the command verifier to actively check the status of the command and see if it worked.

In most cases, the command will have finished successfully and your verifier can then redirect once again to continue normal flow.

If the command fails then the verifier puts up an appropriate error message.

If the command is in progress then you can entire a redirect loop while informing the user that the command is in progress.

Something like:

```
// Execute the command
$command = new CreatePostCommand($title, $content);
$this->commandBus->execute($command);

return redirect '/command-verifier/' . $command->getId();

// The verification action
public function verifyCommandAction($commandId)

$commandStatus = $this->commandBus->getStatus($commandId);

if ($commandStatus == SUCCESS) redirect to all is well;

if ($commandStatus == FAILED) then oops;

if ($commandStatus == IN_PROGRESS) then maybe pause a bit and redirect again while keeping the user informed.
```

Clearly there is quite a bit of hand waving going on but I think this is the most general approach especially with php where every request starts from ground zero.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but that would mean that the $command object at a later point has an id value assigned to it? That would mean it's not immutable. Part of the power of this technique is that your command is signalling an intent, not state or behaviour - this approach breaks that paradigm.

Comment: And the alternative is?  If the intent is to create a post then how would you signal if the post was created or not?

Comment: There's a couple of ways - one is to have the command handler return the successful post creation (standard behaviour), but on error (a bit trickier) you can either throw an exception, or write a service that manages those expectations with the controller injected as an observer dependency that can formulate the correct response based on the result of the command execution.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm currently doing it is as follows (excuse long post).

```
public function createAction($title, $content) {
    try {
        $post = $this->commandBus->execute(new CreatePostCommand($title, $content);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->render('some error template file', $e);
    }

    return $this->render('successful creation template file', $post);
}
```

This way, you're creating a post and if everything goes as planned, return the $post object and send that to your view. On the other hand, when an exception is thrown during execution, you catch that error and send it to a view.

My preferred way is to have the controller call a method on a service that manages that behaviour, and have the controller injected as a listener that manages the responses, ie:

```
public function createAction($title, $content) {
    $service = new CreateActionService($title, $content);

    return $service->create($this);
}

public function onError(Exception $e) {
    return $this->render('some error template file', $e);
}

public function onSuccess($post) {
    return $this->render('success', $post);
}
```

Then in your service...

```
public function create($listener)
{
    try {
        $this->commandBus->execute(new CreatePostCommand($title, $content);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->listener->onError($e);
    }

    return $this->listener->onSuccess($post);
}
```

This way your service is managing the various results that the command handler may return, and your controller is left simply to manage the responses that you may wish returned to your presentation layer.

Comment: Which is fine for when the controller can wait for the command to finish.  But in the land of DDD we have the notion of eventual consistency where it can take minutes, hours or even days to finish an operation. Two completely different problems.

Comment: This is true, especially if you'er talking about things like CQRS systems. In either case, problems can and do occur - and managing it in this fashion means that you neatly take care of any problems that may occur due to unforeseen circumstances.